# Java Server Faces memoy leak Mojarra 2.2.8-35

Tags: jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2, memory-leaks

My application sometimes causes high CPU consumption, we have some cases written in JSF that are often used in large business software.
This problem happens only sometimes and we are unable to identify the cause of the problem.
We are currently using the Mojarra 2.2.8-35 implementation in JBoss EAP 7.3.10.GA.
I imagine that there is some specific component tree that is causing this possible memory leak.
We use Dynatrace APM tool to monitor our environment, the images below demonstrate the memory retention stack at the time of the problem, it can be seen that they are Faces stacks that are experiencing high memory consumption.

[screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beVXe.png)

[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WteUf.png)

[screenshot-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5oYN.png)

I have different stack traces about JSF occurs on thread dump when CPU load is high.
I think that the problem always occurs in the Restore View Phase with postback.
There are many screens developed in JSF with many simultaneous users, it is really complex to discover the screen to simulate the problem, even having a business monitoring tool, there are many requests that are carried out and recorded.

The application runs with a 32Gb heap so a heap dump is difficult to achieve due to its size.

Full Thread Dump avaliable in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BOhz47_bdksiFLL7h-IqrWwP2jHc0McG/view?usp=sharing

```
default task-3237 - Thread t@1882828
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:139)
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:702)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.findChildByTagId(ComponentSupport.java:303)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.findChildByTagId(ComponentSupport.java:331)

default task-3246 - Thread t@1885559
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:699)
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:624)
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.put(ComponentStateHelper.java:104)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setRendererType(UIComponentBase.java:480)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.UIPanel.<init>(UIPanel.java:77)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup.<init>(HtmlPanelGroup.java:76)

default task-3253 - Thread t@1891139
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:699)
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:624)
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.put(ComponentStateHelper.java:155)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.putAttribute(UIComponentBase.java:2604)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2471)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2330)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructionHandler.apply(UIInstructionHandler.java:160)

default task-3271 - Thread t@1891173
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:699)
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:624)
at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.put(ComponentStateHelper.java:155)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.setValueExpression(UIComponent.java:503)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$DynamicValueExpressionMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:129)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)

default task-3275 - Thread t@1892227
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at javax.faces.api:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2383)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.findChildByTagId(ComponentSupport.java:312)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.findChildByTagId(ComponentSupport.java:331)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.findChildByTagId(ComponentSupport.java:331)
at com.sun.jsf-impl:mojarra-2.2.8-35@2.2.8-35//com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.findChildByTagId(ComponentSupport.java:331)
```